# javascriptとhtmlの四則計算

Tags: javascript, monaca, html, html5

いくつか質問している者です。場違いな位初心者で jsもちんぷんかんぷんです。 おかしな返答もあると思います。
下図にあるような画面で数値を入力すると給与の計算をし、計算ボタンの左のテキストボックスに表示させるものを考えています。
細かい計算としては、例えば時間給の計算と交通費などを計算したものの和を表示します。

色々考えて、調べて書いてみたのですがどうしても動きません。　可笑しいところを指摘してほしいです。

文字列から数値に変換する eval()を過去に試していますがそれでも駄目でした。

☆html

```
<ons-template id="tab2.html">
    <ons-page id="second-page">
      <p style="text-align: center;">
        <div align="center">
        </form>
        </div>
        <br>
　<div id="wrapper" align="center">
  <p><form name="frm1" style="display:inline;">時間給：<input type="tel" placeholder="時間" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a10">×<input type="tel" placeholder="時間給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a20"><br>
        <br>日　給：<input type="tel" placeholder="日数" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a11">×<input type="tel" placeholder="日給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a21"><br>
        <br>単位給：<input type="tel" placeholder="単位" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a12">×<input type="tel" placeholder="単位給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a22"><br>
        <br>交通費：<input type="tel" placeholder="交通費" size="8" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a3">円　　　　　　</form><br>
        <br>残　業：<input type="tel" placeholder="時間" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a13">×<input type="tel" placeholder="時給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a23"><br>
        <br>休　日：<input type="tel" placeholder="時間" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a14">×<input type="tel" placeholder="時給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a24"><br>
        <br>深　夜：<input type="tel" placeholder="時間" size="7" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a15">×<input type="tel" placeholder="時給" size="14" style="height:25px; text-align: right;" id="a25"><br>
        <br><input type="text" name="C"><input type="button" value="計算" size="10"id="SumBtn"></form>
        <br><input type="button" value="登録" size="10" id="SaveBtn">
        </p>
</div>
</p>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

☆js

```
function seki(){
　 initsecond-page();
   $("#SumBtn").click(onSumBtn);
   x = document.getElementById("a10");
   x1 = document.getElementById("a11");
   x2 = document.getElementById("a12");
   x3 = document.getElementById("a13");
   x4 = document.getElementById("a14");
   x5 = document.getElementById("a15");
   y = document.getElementById("a20");
   y1 = document.getElementById("a21");
   y2 = document.getElementById("a22");
   y3 = document.getElementById("a23");
   y4 = document.getElementById("a24");
   y5 = document.getElementById("a25");
   t = document.getElementById("a3");
   if(x10 != null){
    z = x * y;
   }
   if(x1 != null){
    z1 = x1 * y1;
   }
   if(x2 != null){
    z2 = x2 * y2;
   }
   if(x3 != null){
    z3 = x3 * y3;
   }
   if(x4 != null){
    z4 = x4 * y4;
   }
   if(x5 != null){
    z5 = x5 * y5;
   } 
    function wa(){
        document.frm1.C.value = (z + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 + t);
    }
}
```

[image: 画面]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: HTMLの表示編集ありがとうございます。

Comment: HTMLの方で`<form>`タグのnameは`frm1`ですが、jsの方での指定は`fm1`になっているように見えます。ここを直しても期待する動作をしませんか？

Comment: 気づいていませんでした！　修正して確かめてみます！

Comment: ダメでした...他の箇所で間違えているようです。朝から色々ありがとうございます！

Comment: あ、あと、if〜else if〜の解釈を間違っていませんか？　このままだと`z`、`z1`〜`z5`は少なくともどれか1つしか定義されません。

Comment: Google chromeを使って開発なさってるのであれば、「開発者ツール」を使ってコンソール上のエラーメッセージを確認すると何か助けになるかもしれません。

Comment: app.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function
    at initTopPage (app.js:35)
    at HTMLDocument.onReady (app.js:66)
    at fire (loader.js:4369)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (loader.js:4481)
    at Function.ready (loader.js:1854)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (loader.js:1549)
initTopPage @ app.js:35
onReady @ app.js:66
fire @ loader.js:4369
fireWith @ loader.js:4481
ready @ loader.js:1854
completed @ loader.js:1549

Comment: appとloaderとの間でのerrorのようです？

Comment: クローズ票を投じました。おそらくMonacaサンプルのメモ帳アプリをベースに`Onsen UI`を組み合わせたコードと思われますが、まずはサンプルのコード一行一行がどのような意味なのか、どのような動きになるのか理解した上で改造を行った方が、アプリ開発もスムーズに進むのではないかと思います。

Comment: 動きは理解出来ていましたが、基礎能力が余りにも低かった様です。場違いな質問すいませんでした。自力でやります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> x = document.getElementById("a10");
> ```

例えばこのコード、[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)が返すのは数値でも文字列でもなく`Element`オブジェクトです。`a10`は`<input type="tel">`なので（なんで`number`じゃないんだろう…）実際に得られるのは[`HTMLInputElement`オブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)です。入力された値は`value`プロパティで参照できますが、それは文字列型となります。四則計算を行うのであれば、文字列型を数値型に変換する必要があります。

…というように、実現しようとしていることに対して書かれているコードからはあまりにも知識不足のように見受けられます。しっかりと基礎を固めることをお勧めします。

Comment: telを指定しているのは スマートフォン上のキーボードの指定のためです numberだとローマ字入力の時に数字以外の物を入力する可能性がある為 それを防ぐためです。

Comment: 知識不足なのは、一昨日jsの勉強を大学での課題の為 始めたばかりで、基礎も一部しか覚えられていない状態です。 すいません。 回答ありがとうございました！ きちんと勉強をします。